# JavaFX : Скроллинг динамически размещаемого контента

Tags: javafx

Есть приложение, предназначенное для визуализации Mind Map. Главная панель организована через BorderPane вот так :

```
 mainAppPanel = new BorderPane();
 MenuBar mainMenu = this.createMainAppMenu(primaryStage);
 mainAppPanel.setTop(mainMenu);
 mainAppPanel.setCenter(mindMap.getMindMapScrollPane());
 StatusBar statusBar = mindMap.getMindMapStatusBar();
 mindMap.updateTextStatusBar("");
 mainAppPanel.setBottom(statusBar);
 return mainAppPanel;
```

То есть верх - menu
середина собственно картинка Mind Map, где Pane объект вложен в ScrollPane
низ - statusbar

При большом числе объектов они начинают вылезать за границы, если объект перетаскивается вниз или вправо, то ScrollPane нормально отрабатывает и позволяет подвинуться вправо или вниз, чтобы увидеть новые объекты. Если новые объекты выползают влево или вверх, то они теряются и проскролить к ним невозможно. Получается, что моя картинка, заполненная объектами карты находится как бы слева вверху области скроллинга и поэтому нет возможности двигаться вверх и влево. Вопрос возможно ли организовать скроллинг во всех направлениях?

ScrollPane Организована вот так

```
this.mindMapScrollPane = new ScrollPane();
this.mindMapPanel = new Pane();
this.mindMapScrollPane.setContent(mindMapPanel);
```

Comment: Первое что напрашивается - сделать так, что бы картинка с объектами была не вверху слева. Задать сразу большие значения у Pane, и отцентровать внутри области скрола. С координатами размещаемых объектов вероятно придется повозиться.

Comment: спасибо, то же догадался, что дело в этом, вот что не ясно, если создал Pane - она что получается безразмерная? Что кажется очень странным. То есть могу добавить объект, но он никогда не будет отрисован, та что ли? Или границы определены размерами сцены?